# Google Charts Y-axes on both sides need to uses the same lines

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Thanks in Advance...!

Query: I want to display my graph where Y-axes on both sides need to use the same lines and add the 7 days interval in the h-axis.

[image]

My code is

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var report_colors     = ["red","yellow","green"];
    var report_columns    = [
                              {"label":"Date","type":"string","name":"X"},
                              {"label":"b","type":"number","name":"b"},
                              {"label":"d","type":"number","name":"d"},
                              {"label":"d\/b","type":"number","name":"d\/b"}
                            ];
    var list      = {"Sep 13, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":6,"d_percnt":1.79,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Sep 14, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":2,"d_percnt":0.6,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Sep 15, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":12,"d_percnt":3.57,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Sep 16, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":20,"d_percnt":5.95,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Sep 17, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":16,"d_percnt":4.76,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Sep 20, 2021":{"b":5,"b_percent":0.84,"d":7,"d_percnt":2.08,"bd":100,"bd_percnt":100},"Sep 21, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":43,"d_percnt":12.8,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Sep 22, 2021":{"b":1,"b_percent":0.17,"d":24,"d_percnt":7.14,"bd":100,"bd_percnt":100},"Sep 23, 2021":{"b":1,"b_percent":0.17,"d":30,"d_percnt":8.93,"bd":100,"bd_percnt":100},"Sep 24, 2021":{"b":9,"b_percent":1.52,"d":19,"d_percnt":5.65,"bd":100,"bd_percnt":100},"Sep 30, 2021":{"b":4,"b_percent":0.67,"d":0,"d_percnt":0,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 01, 2021":{"b":30,"b_percent":5.05,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":3.33,"bd_percnt":3.33},"Oct 04, 2021":{"b":109,"b_percent":18.35,"d":6,"d_percnt":1.79,"bd":5.5,"bd_percnt":5.5},"Oct 05, 2021":{"b":41,"b_percent":6.9,"d":2,"d_percnt":0.6,"bd":4.88,"bd_percnt":4.88},"Oct 06, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":5,"d_percnt":1.49,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 07, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 08, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":4,"d_percnt":1.19,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 10, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":4,"d_percnt":1.19,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 11, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":19,"d_percnt":5.65,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 12, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":7,"d_percnt":2.08,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 18, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 19, 2021":{"b":3,"b_percent":0.51,"d":13,"d_percnt":3.87,"bd":100,"bd_percnt":100},"Oct 21, 2021":{"b":1,"b_percent":0.17,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":100,"bd_percnt":100},"Oct 23, 2021":{"b":4,"b_percent":0.67,"d":0,"d_percnt":0,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 25, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":8,"d_percnt":2.38,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Oct 26, 2021":{"b":1,"b_percent":0.17,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":100,"bd_percnt":100},"Oct 27, 2021":{"b":8,"b_percent":1.35,"d":6,"d_percnt":1.79,"bd":75,"bd_percnt":75},"Oct 28, 2021":{"b":3,"b_percent":0.51,"d":0,"d_percnt":0,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Nov 01, 2021":{"b":2,"b_percent":0.34,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":50,"bd_percnt":50},"Nov 02, 2021":{"b":7,"b_percent":1.18,"d":0,"d_percnt":0,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Nov 10, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":3,"d_percnt":0.89,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Nov 11, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":12,"d_percnt":3.57,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Nov 12, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Nov 14, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":6,"d_percnt":1.79,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Nov 15, 2021":{"b":209,"b_percent":35.19,"d":14,"d_percnt":4.17,"bd":6.7,"bd_percnt":6.7},"Nov 16, 2021":{"b":20,"b_percent":3.37,"d":2,"d_percnt":0.6,"bd":10,"bd_percnt":10},"Nov 17, 2021":{"b":4,"b_percent":0.67,"d":31,"d_percnt":9.23,"bd":100,"bd_percnt":100},"Nov 19, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Nov 22, 2021":{"b":0,"b_percent":0,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Nov 23, 2021":{"b":1,"b_percent":0.17,"d":5,"d_percnt":1.49,"bd":100,"bd_percnt":100},"Nov 25, 2021":{"b":127,"b_percent":21.38,"d":1,"d_percnt":0.3,"bd":0.79,"bd_percnt":0.79},"Nov 26, 2021":{"b":2,"b_percent":0.34,"d":0,"d_percnt":0,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Dec 15, 2021":{"b":1,"b_percent":0.17,"d":0,"d_percnt":0,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0},"Jan 10, 2022":{"b":1,"b_percent":0.17,"d":0,"d_percnt":0,"bd":0,"bd_percnt":0}};
    
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var dataArray = [report_columns];  
    // console.log(report_columns);
    
    $.each(list, function (index, table) {
        console.log(table);  
        dataArray.push([index, table.b ,table.d, table.bd ]);  
    });
    console.log(dataArray);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        fractionDigits: 2,
        suffix: '%'
    });
    formatter.format(data, 3);

    var seriesColors = report_colors;

    var options = {
        // This line makes the entire category's tooltip active.
        focusTarget: 'category',
        // Use an HTML tooltip.
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
        strictFirstColumnType: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '60%',
        'legend': {
          'position': 'none'
        },
        gridlines: {
            color: 'none'
        },
        colors: seriesColors,
        interpolateNulls: false,
        seriesType: 'area',
        pointSize: 5,
        series: {
          2: {
            type: 'line',
            targetAxisIndex:2
          }
        },
        chartArea: {
          left: 40,
          right:40,
          top: 20,
          width: "100%"
        },
        vAxes: [{
            format: 0,
        }, {
            format: "#'%'",
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue:100
        }],
        hAxis: {
            format: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
            title: '',
            textStyle: {
                color: '#b1b8bf',
                fontSize: 10,
                fontName: 'Arial',
                bold: false,
                italic: false
            },
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#b1b8bf',
                fontSize: 10,
                fontName: 'Arial',
                bold: false,
                italic: false
            },
            gridlines:{color:'#CEC7CB'},
            minorGridlines:{color:'#FFFFFF'},
        },
        vAxis: {
            format: "#'%'",
            title: '',
            textStyle: {
                color: '#b1b8bf',
                fontSize: 10,
                bold: false,
                italic: false
            },
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: '#b1b8bf',
                fontSize: 10,
                bold: false,
                italic: false
            },
            gridlines:{color:'#CEC7CB'},
            minorGridlines:{color:'#FFFFFF'},
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById("chart"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: the only way to control the y-axis gridlines is to provide your own `ticks` option for each. same goes for the x-axis (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70673765/5090771)) -- you can try option `showTextEvery: 7` on the x-axis, but this will show every 7th label you provide, not necessarily every 7th day.

Comment: showTextEvery: 7 is a good option but sometimes if we have 10 rows of data, last label tick does not show. start label and last label show everytime

Comment: you can use `ticks` option, but will have to switch from string to dates or numbers